# How to get the interface Methodinfo, based on concrete implementation's MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, interface, attributes

I have an interface `IClass`:

```
public interface IClass
{
    [MyAttribute]
    void Hello();

    [MyAttribute]
    void Farewell();
}
```

And an implementation `Class1`:

```
public class Class1 : IClass
{
    public void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("Hi there") };

    void IClass.Farewell() { Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!") };
}
```

I have a handle on `Class1`'s `MethodInfo`'s for `Hello()` and `IClass.Farewell()` by means of interception, but I need to find the `MethodInfo` of the *interface* definition in order to discover the usage of the attribute `MyAttribute`; something like this:

```
MethodInfo mi = context.Descriptior.CurrentMethod;
MethodInfo imi = GetInterfaceMethodInfo(mi) // ???
var mas = GetCustomAttributes<MyAttribute>();
if (mas.Count > 0)
{
    // Profit!
}
```

**EDIT:**

A point I may have failed to highlight properly: I'm getting the initial `MethodInfo` instance from an interceptor, so I'm trying to find not only the interface's method, but I need to determine if there even is an interface in play, and if so I need to find its method declaration that corresponds to the called method.

I have a workaround that covers my current situation. On the plus side: it works. The downside: It uses string-comparisons, which I find are inherently presumptive.

```
    private bool HasAttribute(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var type = methodInfo.DeclaringType;

        var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

        foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
        {
            var iMethodInfo = @interface.GetMethods()
                .SingleOrDefault(x =>
                    (
                        methodInfo.Name.EndsWith($".{@interface.Name}.{x.Name}") || methodInfo.Name.Equals(x.Name)
                    )
                    && IsSignatureMatch(x, methodInfo)
                );

            if (iMethodInfo != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(iMethodInfo.Name);

                if (iMethodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool IsSignatureMatch(MethodInfo methodInfoA, MethodInfo methodInfoB)
    {
        if (methodInfoA.ReturnType != methodInfoB.ReturnType)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var a = methodInfoA.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToList();
        var b = methodInfoB.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToList();

        if (a.Count != b.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] != b[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I recommand the way using `DeclaringType` and `InterfaceMap` that should be rather safe and not dependent on much string comparison.